What does GDB need to know from memory when connecting to a target?
I am trying to write a GDB stub for a custom chip. Since the target is custom, it needs a GDB stub/server to handle GDB's requests. I seem to be able to handle all the requests GDB gives fine when connecting initially. However, one gives an issue where GDB tries to read at address near zero. Since address near zero are not possible on this chip, this creates an issue.
So, the question is what does GDB try to read from memory when connecting initially to the target? Is the dependent on the ELF file or something more simple?
I hope learning what GDB needs to read from memory on the initial connection will point me in the right direction (maybe I have something mapped wrong in the ELF file?).
I tried looking at the elf file but am not sure what it would tell me.

On a GNU/Linux system, when GDB connects to GDB server there are three reasons why GDB tries reading memory:

Placing software breakpoints, GDB will setup breakpoints to catch things like shared library load/unload events, C++ exception throw/catch events, and C long jump events.  Which of these are created will depend on what environment (OS, libc, etc) you are running in,
On x86-64 GNU/Linux (maybe other architectures too, but I'd have to check), there's a memory mapped vsyscall page (for faster syscall handling), GDB reads some header information from this region to figure out the details of this region,
Finally, stack information is read in order to present the initial stop.  If you are connecting using target remote then the remote inferior is assumed to be running at the point GDB connect.  GDB will read the $pc and $sp registers and then query information from the stack in order to present the initial stop (e.g. stack frame and argument values).

If your custom target is a bare metal setup then the most likely issue is that you are reporting bogus $pc and/or $sp values and as a result GDB is attempting to read memory it shouldn't.
In case you're not aware you can set debug remote on on the GDB side to have GDB report details of what it's doing when it comes to the remote target, though this isn't going to give you much insight into why it's doing these things, but it might help a little.
Another good approach is to just implement memory reading, and have your remote give the reply indicating that the requested memory can't be read, GDB will (hopefully) then give a helpful error indicating what it was trying to do when the read failed.
